# Can numbers having period other than two spontaneously appear in the image of the positive natural numbers, in a 2-adic isometry?

Tags: metric-spaces, induction, p-adic-number-theory, isometry

Let $T:\Bbb Z_2\to\Bbb Z_2$ be a bijective 2-adic isometry satisfying $T(0)=0$ and $T(2x)=2T(x)$ and $T(1)=\overline{01}_2$.

For all $y\in\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z_2$ such that $y<x$, let $T(y)$ be eventually cyclic with period $2$.

**Question**

Is it possible for there to be some positive integer $x\in\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z_2$ such that $T(x)$ never becomes cyclic with period $2$?

**Motivation**

I'm trying to better understand the rules of isometries in the context of integers embedded in the 2-adic space. An example would be useful.

**My poor attempt - such as it is**

I've tried to create a counterexample but failed.  But I also feel like my attempt wasn't a strong attempt.

I can see how the $\overline{01}_2$ string has the potential to constrain possible choices for $T(x)$, especially given that $T(2^ny):n\in\Bbb N$ are all already picked, and picking $T(x)$ also picks $T(2^mx):m\in\Bbb N$.

Comment: In "For all $y\in\Bbb N\subset\Bbb Z_2$ such that $y<x$, let ..." -- what is $x$? Also, $\overline{01}_2$ is the $2$-adic representation of $-1/3$, right? (Just checking we agree on how to write them.)

Comment: If you are kind of asking this for any natural number $x$, then I think a counterexample for $x =3$ is just given by letting $T$ be multiplication with $-1/3$ for all $2^m x$ with $x \equiv 1$ mod $4$, but multiplication with (say) $-1/7$ for all $2^m x$ with $x \equiv 3$ mod $4$. It seems harder to cook up counterexamples for higher $x$, my bet would be it's still possible though.

Comment: Thank-you @TorstenSchoeneberg very interesting I'll examine your example. If there's a proof it's impossible for higher numbers, it proves the Collatz conjecture so it would be worth any time invested.  Moreover, if the exceptions are only a few edge cases, the conditions I've given could be tightened up to eliminate them. A game might be interesting where you cook up examples and I use my knowledge of the conjecture to tighten up the rules. If we arrive at a proof there are no more examples, it would be a proof of the conjecture.

Comment: @TorstenSchoeneberg ...for example, I can add the following rule: if $x\equiv1\pmod2$ then $T(4x+1)=4T(x)-3$