# To what extent do the fixed points of this isometry on natural numbers in the 2-adic space constrain the isometry?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, p-adic-number-theory, isometry

Consider an isometric homeomorphism $T$ on the 2-adic integers $\Bbb Z_2$, which fixes the numbers $-1,0$ and exchanges $(-1/3,1)$, and obeys $2T(x)=T(2x)$.

I'm aware that, in general, p-adic isometries continue to enjoy a lot of freedom even after many points are determined, but I can also see scope for these rules to be quite restrictive.

Is it possible that these rules give rise to a single, canonical isometry, particularly on the natural number $\Bbb N$ subset of $\Bbb Z_2$?

Comment: This seems very similar to your previous https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4395196/96384, and the same idea as in the comment there should work: Set $T(x) = -\frac13 x$ for $x \equiv 1$ mod $8$, $T(x) = -3x$ for $x \equiv 5 \equiv -\frac13$ mod $8$, $T(x) = \alpha x$ for $x \equiv 3, 7$ mod $8$ where $\alpha$ can be anything $\in 1+8 \mathbb Z_2$, and via the condition $T(2x)=2T(x)$ everywhere else. You can refine this and have much more choice if you start with a partition modulo higher $2^n$.

Comment: Ah I see you want $-1$ to be fixed. Then in the above set $T(x)=x$ for $x \equiv 7$ mod $8$, but you are still free to choose $\alpha$ for $x \equiv 3$ mod $8$. And again, for fine partitions you'll have more choices.